# I have created a virtual table and trying to update some columns but its not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update the virtual table I have created but it's throwing an error when I am running this in an online editor:

```
Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 no such table: Table_Ex)
```

If I give a select statement instead of an update, it's working.
Please look into the code.

```
 with Table_EX as
    (select C.CustomerID, C.Country, O.CustomerID, O.ShipperID
    from Customers C Inner Join Orders O on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
    where C.CustomerID = '4')
    update Table_EX
    SET 
    Country = 'INDIA' 
    ,ShipperID = '420';
```

Comment: error message is like "no such table"
but the select statement is working fine

Comment: You should include the actual error given for best help, not just an abbreviated form.

Comment: Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 no such table: Table_Ex)

Comment: That would mean `Table_Ex` does not exist in your database and cannot be used in part or all of your query.

Comment: If I give a select statement I can view the data